# Embed SSL root certificate in iOS app instead of installing it for the whole system

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, ssl-certificate

How can I embed a custom CA SSL certificate in an application that connects to a local server?

This certificate should work like any CA certificate installed in the system, but embedded in this application instead of requiring the user to install it system-wide, so it won't show a security warning and only works with our local servers through the application

The need for this is to comply with ATS without needing the user to do any further configuration like downloading and installing the CA Certificate manually

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're working with a self-signed certificate, in which case, what you're looking for is **SSL pinning**.

Depending on whether you're using a network lib or not, this might work differently, but what you want to do is store a public cert, and then handle the authentication challenge manually:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/handling_an_authentication_challenge

For example:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {  
    guard let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust, SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trust) > 0 else {
        // This case will probably get handled by ATS, but still...
        completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        return
    }

    // Or, compare the public keys
    if let serverCertificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0), let serverCertificateKey = publicKey(for: serverCertificate) {
        if pinnedKeys().contains(serverCertificateKey) {
            completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: trust))
            return
        }
    }

    completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
}


fileprivate func pinnedKeys() -> [SecKey] {
    var publicKeys: [SecKey] = []

    if let pinnedCertificateURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "infinumco", withExtension: "crt") {
        do {
            let pinnedCertificateData = try Data(contentsOf: pinnedCertificateURL) as CFData
            if let pinnedCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, pinnedCertificateData), let key = publicKey(for: pinnedCertificate) {
                publicKeys.append(key)
            }
        } catch (_) {
            // Handle error
        }
    }

    return publicKeys
}
```

I have a couple of other examples how to handle this scenario here:

https://github.com/Adis/swift-ssl-pin-examples